# Will other players be able to see my discoveries if I upload them while connection is lost?

Tags: no-mans-sky

There's an indicator in the lower left corner of the discoveries menu that shows if you are currently connected to the servers or not. If I upload my discoveries while it says I'm not connected, will it upload them for other players to see once it gains a connection again?

Answer (score 4):

Based on posts I've read, it sounds like it will save the discoveries you've made and attempt to upload them for real when you *do* go back online.

> And for those who think "But when you explore a world and upload it, what happens in Offline?" well it just waits to be uploaded, until you enter with an online connection again.

However, this could pose an issue if two players discover the same thing while one is offline-- it would appear to be a new discovery to both players, but only one name would be able to be the *official* name. Other posts suggest that the system would use a first-come first-served basis.

> It's who ever uploads it first. So if one in online and one offline the online presone gets it. If both are offline, who ever goes online and uploads first gets it.

Source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/0/366298942113140424/

Comment: I wonder how they know that. It seems like it'd be really hard to test.

Comment: Well the system seems to be that once a name has been uploaded, it can't be changed, and the option to rename is removed. If someone offline discovered something but didn't go online to officially upload it until after someone playing online discovered and uploaded it, I feel like the server would just block any attempted uploads for that system/planet/animal/plant, causing the online player's name to be the "official" one.

Comment: It makes sense, of course, but did they verify it actually gets uploaded? You'd have to have someone else in your system to check that, wouldn't you? There are a lot of mechanics that don't work how one might expect, so I'd like some confirmation, if possible.

Comment: It would be extremely difficult to coordinate a test for this. I wish I could give a definitive answer with documented proof, but the best I've found is extrapolation of known game mechanics. For a game of this scope, I think that's the best you'll get for a while.

Comment: I suspect you're right, unfortunately. I did come across an article about discoveries not being saved: http://www.polygon.com/2016/8/26/12660812/no-mans-sky-discoveries-wiped-first-planets I wonder if it's related to not being connected to the servers.

Comment: I saw that as well. I also read somewhere about the possibility of an accept/reject system for names on the server level